# How to pass a parameter to a Blazor service?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a service like this sample code below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace BasicDependencyInjection
{
  public interface IToDoApi
  {
    Task<IEnumerable<ToDo>> GetToDosAsync();
  }
  public class ToDoApi : IToDoApi
  {
    private readonly IEnumerable<ToDo> Data;
    public ToDoApi()
    {
      Data = new ToDo[]
      {
        new ToDo { Id = 1, Title = "To do 1", Completed = true},
        new ToDo { Id = 2, Title = "To do 2", Completed = false},
        new ToDo { Id = 3, Title = "To do 3", Completed = false},
      };
    }
    public Task<IEnumerable<ToDo>> GetToDosAsync() => Task.FromResult(Data);
  }
}
```

It's not my code, just a sample code taken [a tutorial page](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/injecting-dependencies-into-blazor-components/)

And here is how the service is registerd.

```
service.AddSingeton<IToDoApi, ToDoApi>();
```

My question is, I need to pass a value to the service, namely to the `ToDoApi()` method.

How can this be done? How can I pass a token to the service for example without hardcoding it in the code.

One more thing, I can't pass a param to the register method, I would like to pass a param whenever I am using the service in my compoents, because the token to provide the service comes from components.

Thanks

Comment: Add a method that accepts a parameter to the interface and service, and then inject the Interface in the components and call the method

Comment: "because the token to provide the service comes from components" You are planning to use different API access tokens depending on what the user does with various components in your UI? You aren't managing user access tokens by tying them in some way to your auth system? Are you using an auth system?

Comment: Hi, @keithwill-the-upvoter let me clarify, I am basically fetching the Github API, but I have two components e.g., `/users`, `/user-profiles` that need to fetch a specific URL e.g., `/api/users`. This means, instead of duplicating the code needed to fetch the URL, I prefer to create a service and share it whenever I need it. Problem is the service itself needs to accept a parameter (URL to github) ... the URL is not static though, there is an ID in the URL that changes (but this is easy, I can get the ID from my current browser url) e.g., `http://localhost/users/323` - hope this helps

Comment: Is the ID associated with the authenticated user of your web app in any way?

Comment: @keithwill-the-upvoter No, there is nothing that needs authentication here. ID is fetched from the URL, but I need to pass the ID into the service so I can make authenticated fetch from inside the service. Only the code inside the service does auth .. but it needs that ID first

Comment: So, you need to pass a route parameter in your Blazor component as a method call parameter to your service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```cs
public class ToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}

public interface IToDoApi
{
    Task<IEnumerable<ToDo>> GetToDosAsync();
}

public class ToDoApi : IToDoApi
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ToDo> Data;

    private bool initialized;
    
    public ToDoApi()
    {
        Data = new ToDo[]
        {
        new ToDo { Id = 1, Title = "To do 1", Completed = true},
        new ToDo { Id = 2, Title = "To do 2", Completed = false},
        new ToDo { Id = 3, Title = "To do 3", Completed = false},
        };
    }
    public void Initialize(bool initialize)
    {
        initialized = initialize;
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<ToDo>> GetToDosAsync()
    {
        if (!initialized)
            throw new Exception("You must initialize ToDoAPI before trying to use it");
        
        return Task.FromResult(Data);
    } 
}
```

You call `Initialize` from your component that gets the data and pass in whatever data you want.  I've made it simplistic by just passing in the actual bool.

Service registration:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ToDoApi>();
```

Here's a demo page:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject ToDoApi Service

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="p-2 m-2 ">
    Records: @list.Count();
</div>

<div class="p-2 m-2 ">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="First">Unsafe</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Second">Safe</button>
</div>
@code {
    IEnumerable<ToDo> list = Enumerable.Empty<ToDo>();

    private async Task First()
    {
        list = await Service.GetToDosAsync();
    }

    private async Task Second()
    {
        Service.Initialize(true);
        list = await Service.GetToDosAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you add an example on how to instantiate and actually pass the param?

Comment: You should mark this guy as the accepted solution. He provided an answer to your question. More info on using route parameters can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-parameters

Comment: See  my modified answer with an example.